# rebase virtualbox snapshot to another parent

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, snapshot

I'm excessively using VirtualBox snapshots  (for use in CI-builders), so typically I have a number of snapshots on a single VM.
Often I find my self "forking" a new snapshot from an existing one, e.g. for updating the system:

```
base
└── A
    └── A1
```

Once the udpate completes, I replace the parent snapshot with its child, by simply removing `A`, VirtualBox will then merge the changeset `base->A` and `A->A1`:

```
base
└── A1
```

Cool.

However, sometimes I want to create a new snapshot subtree, that *originally* forks of some snapshot, and gets a life of its own:

E.g.

```
base
└── A
    ├── A1
    └── B
        └── B1
```

Now: this gets ugly pretty soon (as i keep updating the subtree), and eventually i like to clean up the snapshot tree, so it becomes:

```
base
├── A1
└── B1
```

Unfortunately, VirtualBox does not allow me to delete snapshot `A` with the following error:

```
Snapshot 'A' of the machine 'vagrantbox' cannot be deleted, because it has 2 child snapshots, which is more than the one snapshot allowed for deletion.
```

In theory I do not see any problems with deleting snapshot `A`: VirtualBox simply has to perform the snapshot merging twice (`base->A->A1` and `base->A->B`). This will probably grow the snapshot size, but I can happily live with that (and hopefully i will get better performance by reducing the FS-layers)

So: how can I rebase a snapshot to a parent, while leaving sibling snapshots intact?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a full VM clone based on a snapshot. The new VM will not have any snapshots. The only other way is to de-register the VM, then do all the work yourself by using `vboxmanage` on the disk images and editing the VM's XML file.